# Populate a property based on a request

Tags: c#

I have a class called "BookingRequest" with some properties.

I want that when I create a BookingRequest one of the properties is set based on a value sent to the class

(class reduced for brevity)

```
 public class BookingRequest 
        {
            public BookingRequest()
            {
                Description = $"{Procedure.Data.Id.First()}, booked";
            }
            
            public string? Uid { get; set; } = null;
    
            public string Type { get; } = "bookings";
    
            private string Description { get; }

            public Relationship<Procedures> Procedure { get; init; } = null!;
       
         }
```

how would this be done? this doesn't seem to be working

When I create the Booking request object I send a "Procedure"

the object then gets created with

the object gets created with

```
    body.Data = new BookingRequest() {
        Start = bookingRequestQuery.Start,
        End = bookingRequestQuery.End,
        EMailAddress = bookingRequestQuery.EmailAddress,
        PhoneNumberCell = bookingRequestQuery.PhoneNumberCell,
        FirstName = bookingRequestQuery.FirstName,
        LastName = bookingRequestQuery.LastName,
        Clinic = clinic,
        Organizer = organizer,
        Procedure = procedure,
        Timestamp = _clock.UtcNow
    };
```

Comment: What are your `Relationship` and `Procedures` classes? I don't think they are part of the default library

Comment: `Procedure.Data.Id.First()` won't work because at the point where the constructor runs, `Procedure` won't have a value. You should accept `Procedure` as a constructor argument.